# Appending list index number to matrix items as a new column

Tags: r

Simple question no doubt. Taking this starting point:

```
l = matrix(1:6, ncol=2)
lst = list(l, l)
```

How can I add the list index as a fresh column to each matrix? e.g.

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    1
[2,]    2    5    1
[3,]    3    6    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    2
[2,]    2    5    2
[3,]    3    6    2
```

... assuming the matrices have varying numbers of rows.  I've attempted various permutations of `lapply` with no luck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly simpler. Practically any problem involving applying a function to each element of two (or 3, or n) objects in order can be given an `mapply` or `Map` solution (thanks, @mnel):

```
mapply(cbind, lst, seq_along(lst), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# ...and with Map being a wrapper for mapply with no simplification
Map(cbind, lst, seq_along(lst))

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    1
[2,]    2    5    1
[3,]    3    6    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    2
[2,]    2    5    2
[3,]    3    6    2
```

Comment: `map` is shorter wrapper `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`

Comment: @mnel - updated to include `Map` (with a capital) in the answer

Comment: Yes I think this deserves the tick, as its a more flexible solution: e.g. additional vector data can be appended as columns, rather than just list index info. Then e.g. list items can be combined with `do.call(rbind, lst)` into a single data.frame..

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(seq_along(lst), function(idx) {
    unname(cbind(lst[[idx]], idx))
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun! Surprisingly complex solution.